# WPF TreeView showing only root element

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to create dyamic tree structure, i have red some tutorials but i can't get it right. My wpf treeview is only showing root element. What am I doing wrong?

Here is MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Leaf}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">            
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my node class

```
class Leaf
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Access { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public List<Leaf> Childs;

    public Leaf()
    {
        this.Name = "default";
        this.Childs = new List<Leaf>();
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Leaf> mainlist = new List<Leaf>();

        Leaf one = new Leaf();
        one.Name = "one";

        var two = new Leaf();
        two.Name = "two";

        one.Childs.Add(two);

        mainlist.Add(one);

        tv.DataContext = mainlist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that List of Leafs should look like this:

> public List Childs {get; set;}

Problem solved, sorry for truble.